# A modern substitue for "kith and kin"

Tags: idioms, expressions

In old-fashioned English, the term **"kith and kin"** encompass all the people you've been connected with, including the nuclear and extended family members.
What is its modern substitute if exists?

**First scenario:**

Imagine you're talking to a gypsy and want to ask him informally whether they have any relatives or friends close to him geographically.

> Do you have any **kith and kin** in this city?

**Second scenario:**

Let's suppose a police officer who after a bad cat accident comes to an injured person on the street who is unable to talk about their relatives or friends that can come along with him/her. What would the officer ask his/her subordinates?

> Try to find his/her **kith and kin**.

Comment: What about "relative"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern expression for [*kith*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kith) and [*kin*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kin) is simply ***friends and family***.

---

Note that in your first example sentence, it would be more natural to say, "*Do you have any kith **or** kin in this city?* Which, of course, would become *Do you have any friends **or** family in this city?*

Comment: And @Jason Bassford in my second instance would it work to say: "**Try to find his/her friends or family**" or "**Try to call his friends or family.**" ? That's just a bit confusing to me how to use "and" or "or" in my scenarios.

Comment: @A-friend In the second sentence, both conjunctions work. If they are trying to find *all* friends and family, then *and* is fine. But if they are just looking for *some* (or *any*), then *or* would work.